# What does this mean ls(pat=“^V")?

Tags: r

How it is used and what does it mean?

```r
ls(pat=“^V")
```

Comment: I found answers after 30 seconds of googling: for instance https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ls and https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-ls-function-in-r and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/list-all-the-objects-present-in-the-current-working-directory-in-r-programming-ls-function/ - perhaps you should just experiment with the function and see what it does when you use it. That's a good way to learn.

Answer (score 2):

This is short for `ls(pattern="^V")`, which means "list all objects in the workspace whose names start with "V" ("^" is a regular expression code meaning 'beginning of string')